# Splitting a string using RegEx matches instead of delimiters

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to split a string like this: `"1.2 5"` to be tokenized to `{"1", ".", "2", "5"}` (order matters), I was trying to do this with `String.split()` using the following regex: `([0-9])\w*|\.` but this is what I want to match, not the delimiters.

Is there maybe another method that does this? Is it even possible to split two words that are connected while keeping both intact? (e.g split "1.2" like the above example)

More examples:

`"1 2 8"` => `{"1", "2", "8"}`

`"1 122 .8"` => `{"1", "122", "." "8"}`

`"1 2.800"` => `{"1", "2", "." "800"}`

Comment: Just match with `\S`.

Comment: But there might not be a space between `1.2` @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: See http://ideone.com/As4Rpx. `\S` is a non-whitespace.

Comment: You should add other example strings (with the desired results) to well explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Added @CasimiretHippolyte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work ([demo](http://ideone.com/ccSIjB)):

```
s.split("(?=\\.)(?<! )|(?<=\\.)| +")
```

It works by spliting on places in the string where:

- the next character is a literal `.` (lookahead) and the preceding character is **not** a space (negative lookbehind)
- the preceding character is a literal `.` (lookbehind)
- there are one or more space characters

The java split function removes any matching part of the string. In the case of the lookahead/lookbehind matches, they are are zero-width so split doesn't actually consume any of the string when spliting. The zero-width match basically just marks a position in the string to split at.

This solution will works for all your given examples, and it also works for multiple spaces. Here's a [demo](http://ideone.com/ccSIjB).

---

In response to your comment about the `(?<! )` part of the regex. Without that part, The pattern matches every space character, and the position before every `.` and after every `.`. One of your examples had a space followed by a `.` (e.g. `"2 .8"`) which would split like this:

```
["2", "", ".", "8"]
```

Note the empty string in the 2nd position. This is because it has split on the space, and then found a position before a `.`, and split there too. The `(?<! )` prevents this by saying "only split before a `.` if it's not preceded by a space character.

Comment: Why was adding `(?<! )` important?

Comment: There is really no need for such a complex regex here, you can just match all digits or all non-digit/non-whitespace symbols with a much simpler expression. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather collect all the non-digit and non-whitespace symbols with `[^\d\s]` and digits with a `\d`:

```
String s = "1.2 5";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+|[^\\d\\s]+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()){
    lst.add(matcher.group(0));
} 
System.out.println(lst);  // => [1, 122, ., 8]
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/j8k0Re)

**Pattern details**:

- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `|` - or
- `[^\d\s]+` - one or more chars other than a whitespace or digit

And here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zM0dC5/1).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex matching, java has a built-in `StringTokenizer` that is just for this.

Try this:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("1.2 5", ". ");
while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    System.out.println(st.nextToken());
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
5
```

EDIT: and if you want to include the delimiters, use new StringTokenizer(string, delimiters, returnDelims=true). In that case, the output is:

```
1
.
2

5
```

If you just want to return the dot, but not the space, skip it in the loop.